# Percentage of time left with two given timestamps Javascript

Tags: javascript, percentage

I've got two `Date()` times and I'm trying to use the difference between them to set the width of a progress bar shrinking from 100% to 0% when there is no more difference between the times, but I'm getting really strange results.

This is how I'm trying to do it currently (it's being split across a couple of different functions in React so I'll just include the code that is relevant) :

First I set up the target datetime which sets the `endDate` to the top of the hour within the next 24hrs (e.g 10pm exactly)...

```
this.endDate = new Date();

if (this.props.data.end_hr === 0) {
    this.endDate.setHours(24, 0, 0, 0);
} else {
    this.endDate.setHours(this.props.data.end_hr);
}
this.endDate.setMinutes(0);
this.endDate.setSeconds(0);

this.countdown = setInterval(this.timeRemaining, 1000);
```

Then in the `timeRemaining` function, which fires every second, I'm getting the current datetime and calculating the difference between them. Lastly I'm trying to work out a percentage to send to the progress bar css width property...

```
let now = new Date().getTime();
let diff = this.endDate - now;

let percent =
  Math.round(((diff / this.endDate) * 100000000 * 2) / 100) + '%';

this.countdownProgress.style.width = percent;
```

The `diff` is 100% correct but the percentage is wrong.

I've tried every different way of calculating the percentage that I could think of but nothing works as expected, the method above was the closest I could get.

Could somebody show me where I'm going wrong please?

**Edit**: @Danziger's answer implemented in the way that I want to use it. This sets the start time at 10pm and the end time at midnight.

It turns out that it does work correctly so I must have something else in my code causing the issue. Thanks again to Danziger for showing me light!

```js
const progressBar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
const progressText = document.getElementById('progressText');

const startDate = new Date();
startDate.setHours(22);
startDate.setMinutes(0);
startDate.setSeconds(0);

const endDate = new Date();
endDate.setHours(24,0,0,0);
endDate.setMinutes(0);
endDate.setSeconds(0);

const range = endDate - startDate;

function updateCountdown() {
  const diff = Math.max(0, endDate - new Date());
  
  progressBar.style.width = `${ 100 * diff / range }%`;
  progressText.innerText = `${ `000${ Math.ceil(diff / 1000) }`.slice(-4) } seconds`
  
  if (diff >= 0) {
    requestAnimationFrame(updateCountdown);
  }  
}

updateCountdown();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.progressBar__base {
  position: relative;
  height: 32px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 0 0 8px;
}

.progressBar__progress {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="progressBar__base">
  <div class="progressBar__progress" id="progressBar"></div>
</div>

<div id="progressText"></div>
```

Comment: You’re calculating `diff / endDate`, when you’re looking to calculate `diff / (endDate - startDate)` - that is `diff` as a percentage of the total time between `startDate` and `endDate`. Also, using your current definition for `diff` will give you a *decreasing* progress bar. If you want an *increasing* one, use `diff = now - startDate` instead.

Comment: Just tried that - `Math.round(diff / (this.endDate - now))` and I'm getting `1` back? The endDate in question is currently set to midnight UK and it's currently 22:29 here at the moment.

Comment: Ahh so  I need to supply a start date? I'm not doing that. Only an endDate and the current time

Comment: If you don’t have a start date, you can’t know how much progress has been made. That’s like asking “*Given that you’ve travelled 200 miles, how much of your journey to Toronto have you covered?*”

Comment: Yep makes total sense, my brain was just having a mad half hour I think :D

Comment: We’ve all been there :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to divide `diff` by some range, in this case, the time difference you had initially (which is its maximum value), not by `endDate`:

```js
const progressBarDescending = document.getElementById('progressBarDescending');
const progressBarAscending = document.getElementById('progressBarAscending');
const progressTextDescending = document.getElementById('progressTextDescending');
const progressTextAscending = document.getElementById('progressTextAscending');

const startDate = new Date();
const endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + 10000); // + 10 seconds
const range = endDate - startDate;

function updateCountdown() {
  const diff = Math.max(0, endDate - new Date());
  
  progressBarDescending.style.width = `${ 100 * diff / range }%`;
  progressBarAscending.style.width = `${ 100 - 100 * diff / range }%`;
  
  progressTextDescending.innerText = `${ `000${ Math.ceil(diff / 1000) }`.slice(-4) } seconds left`;
  progressTextAscending.innerText = `${ `000${ Math.floor((range - diff) / 1000) }`.slice(-4) } seconds elapsed`;
  
  if (diff >= 0) {
    requestAnimationFrame(updateCountdown);
  }  
}

updateCountdown();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.progressBar__base {
  position: relative;
  height: 32px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 16px 0 8px;
}

.progressBar__progress {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="progressBar__base">
  <div class="progressBar__progress" id="progressBarDescending"></div>
</div>

<div id="progressTextDescending"></div>

<div class="progressBar__base">
  <div class="progressBar__progress" id="progressBarAscending"></div>
</div>

<div id="progressTextAscending"></div>
```

So, let's say you start this countdown at `startDate = 5` and `endDate = 15`, so your `range = 10`.

If you want to update the `diff` after `5` seconds, that would be `diff = endDate - now = endDate - 10 = 5`. Then, `progress = 100 * diff / range = 100 * 5 / 10`, **not** `progress = 100 * diff / endDate = 100 * 5 / 15`.

Comment: Thank you very much. After importing the start time (which is required as this is a scheduled event) and following your method it now seems to be showing the correct percentage but it's ascending. i.e it's showing 40% when I need it to output 60% as my bar is reducing from right to left. Any idea how I flip that result?

Comment: Ignore that last comment, it is counting down, but again it doesn't appear to be displaying the correct percentage. The difference between the start and end times are set to 2 hours apart in real time (start 10pm end midnight) (uk). But right now at 11pm it's saying there is only 34% left when it should be around 50%. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please update the code in your question with what you currently have if you have changed anything?

Comment: Hey bro, I've just edited your code to work with specified start and end times and added it to my original question. It does indeed work as it should so I must have something else going on in my code somewhere that is throwing it off.

Answer (score 7):

I think your problem is that you don't have a defined `startTime` to use as a reference and instead you're using `now`.

If you had a `startTime`, you would do:

```
let now = new Date().getTime();
let totalTime = endTime - startTime;
let progress = now - startTime;
let percentage = (progress / totalTime) * 100;
```

I'm not actually sure what value you're getting with your own calculation.

Comment: The endDate will always be anything within the next 24hrs on the hour. So if it was 5:30 now the endDate could be 7:00 for example. endDate is always in the future.

Comment: Thank you, so I need to supply a start time too? I thought I could do it just with the endDate and current time but that's not possible I guess?

Comment: If you think about it, what would you be taking the percentage of if you only had current time and end time? Your current time would represent progress of what range? Are you always at 0% progress until you're at 100%?

Comment: You could also draw an analogy between test scores. They're usually between 0 and some score. A test score of 5/10 implies that you achieved 5 marks in the range of 0 marks and 10 marks.

Comment: Thank you - wasted HOURS trying to do this myself. Works great, just set the variables.